# Mobile push notifications setup and user targeting

Tags: push-notification, onesignal

I am trying to setup Push notifications in the mobile app. I have decided to use OneSignal for this. This topic is completely new for me and I would like to know the best practices regarding Push notifications setup in terms of user targeting. From what I got from the Google and OneSignal documentation I can target different user in two ways:

1. In the mobile app assign some data tags to users, e.g. 'hasItems: true', or 'isInterestedInProduct' and then create segments in OneSignal console with these user tags.
2. Save OneSignal `PlayerId` on my backend, match it with the `userId` and then selectively send messages to the users depending on the backend database data.

What is the preferred way to do this? Or it should be the combination of both depending on my use cases?
Is there any way to make it fully automatized? E.g. based on some analytics events, create messages in OneSignal without any changes from the mobile/backend side (only setup the mobile sdk )?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your use case.

For sending messages to users as a group, tags are a great way to support this. For example, you could tag all users interested in a specific product, or who have visited a specific page in your app. [Here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/add-user-data-tags) is OneSignal's guide on tags.

For sending messages to a small list of specific users, storing their OneSignal player_id or using the external_id feature of OneSignal is the way to go. [Here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/transactional-messages) is OneSignal's guide on sending these types of notifications.